# Getting error while updating an image into database using Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbc-postgres

I tried the code below. I'm using both image and text for update, but I'm getting an application error. Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of this error I'm getting.

```
QuestionRef questionRef = ceBean.get("questionRef");
QuestionRef oldQuestionRef = this.getQuestionRef(ceBean);
questionRef.setAnswerId(oldQuestionRef.getAnswerId());
int i = 0;
MultipartFile[] answerImage = questionRef.getAnswerImage();
for (String answer : questionRef.getAnswerId()) {
    QuestionAns questionAns = new QuestionAns();
    if (answerImage[i].getSize() > 0) {         
        questionAns.setImage_answer(XUtil.encodeToBase64(answerImage[i].getBytes()));
        ceBean.put("questionAns", questionAns);
        questionRefDAO.updateAnswerImage(ceBean);
    }
    else if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(questionRef.getAnswer()[i])) {
        ceBean.put("questionAns", questionAns);
        questionRefDAO.updateAnswer(ceBean);
    }
    i++;
}
Long q_id = questionRef.getQuestion_id();
questionRef.setQuestion_id(q_id);       
ceBean.put("questionRef", questionRef);
questionRefDAO.updateQuestionRef(ceBean);
```

Comment: Please don't shout :(

Comment: when did i shouted?.. @BackSlash

Comment: When you use the CAPS LOCK IT SEEMS YOU ARE SHOUTING US

Comment: oh i don't know that sorry..@BackSlash

Comment: this is my updating answer's BO part same thing i used it in my program